# Can't find asp.net mvc 6 Template Application's Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an new asp.net 5 web application(mvc).

In config.json, this is connection string:

`"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-sampleProject-be728759-6d45-4ac9-bb6c-f55ac4aee69e;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`

But when I connect to `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb` from sql server management studio, I don't see this database: `aspnet5-sampleProject-be728759-6d45-4ac9-bb6c-f55ac4aee69e`

[image: mssqllocaldb databases list]

I'm really stuck!

How I can connect to this database?

Comment: You still need to create the database. If you're using Entify Framework for data access, you can run EF migrations to initialize the DB. Or just use a SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easy.

I created a database and add its ConnectionString in config.json.

Migration run automatically and membership tables added to database.

Answer (score 1):

As of now MVC 6 doesn't create database when application runs for first time. Database creation is separate aspect at present. Use EF migrations to create DB.

Please run EF commands present in project.json to create database as shown  [Create Your Database](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html#create-your-database)

ASP.NET 5 and EF 7 team are working for tooling experience.